# Page not returning results

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

i have node js + express 4 issues. i'm trying to call a function in index.js from login.js and get an answer printed out, but it doesn't even give me an error cause.
console log gives me what i want in the console , but it doesn't render on the page.

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var login = require('./login.js');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* Check login status */
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
var response = login.logintest();
res.send(response);

});

module.exports = router;
```

login.js:

```
/* LOAD all requires needed here */
var request = require('request');
    request = request.defaults({jar: true});
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
/*
 * GET logincheck check if user needs to login
 */

exports.logintest = logintest;

function logintest(req, res)
      {
      request.get('http://internalbusinessdomain.com/', getStatus);
      };
function getStatus(err, mess, body)
      {
        if (!err && mess.statusCode == 200)
        {
            // console.log(body) ;
          var $Cheers=cheerio.load(body);
          // console.log($Cheers('li').text());
          if ($Cheers('li').text().substring(0,8) == "Inloggen"){
            console.log("htli")
            return "hastologin";

          }
          else {console.log("verbonden");
            return "connected";
          };
        }
        else
        { console.log("niet verbonden met tln");
          return "notconnected";
        };
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use callback instead of returns your code looks like this

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var login = require('./login.js');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* Check login status */
router.get('/login', login.logintest);

module.exports = router;
```

login.js

```
var request = require('request');
    request = request.defaults({jar: true});
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
/*
 * GET logincheck check if user needs to login
 */

exports.logintest = logintest;

function logintest(req, res){
    request.get('http://internalbusinessdomain.com/',function (err, mess, body){
        if (!err && mess.statusCode == 200){
            // console.log(body) ;
            var $Cheers=cheerio.load(body);
            // console.log($Cheers('li').text());
            if ($Cheers('li').text().substring(0,8) == "Inloggen"){
                console.log("htli")
                res.send("hastologin");
            }else {
                console.log("verbonden");
                res.send("connected");
            };
        }else{
            console.log("niet verbonden met tln");
            res.send("notconnected");
        };  
    });
}
```

Comment: nope...
ReferenceError: res is not defined
    at Request.getStatus (C:\xxxxxx\routes\login.js:25:13)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\xxxxx\node_modules\request\request.js:373:22)